# changing image when switch from dark mode to light in Ionic5 Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

Hi I'm trying to switch the image when going from dark to light mode or vs versa.
I've tried the following with no success;

HTML

```
<picture>
  <source 
    srcset="dark.png" 
    media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
  <img src="light.png">
</picture>
```

CSS

```
#screenshot {
        background-image: url(settings-light.png);
      }

      @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
        #screenshot {
          background-image: url(settings-dark.png);
        }
      }
```

I have a toggle button to switch from dark to light which is out of the box with Ionic 5 side menu.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: No didn't get a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1):

I actually was totally overcomplicating this.

Ionic provides a media query we can tap into.

Did you try this out?

https://dev.to/nodefiend/changing-dark-light-image-on-ionic-5-react-ios-app-57m5

Comment: How does that work? Can you provide an answer to the Question here in this post, please?

Comment: I recommend against rhetoric questions in answers. They risk being misunderstood as not an answer at all. You are trying to answer the question at the top of this page, aren't you? Otherwise please delete this post.

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."